How do I add a pipe node in HEC-RAS?
I am new to using HEC-RAS and I have issues with it.
I have a 2D project in HEC-RAS version 6.5. I have created my 2D flow area and my upstream and downstream boundary conditions. Here is the image:


I added two dams (or weirs) with culverts running through them as 2D connections and used the "Enforce internal connection as break line" tool to change the orientation of the cells. One of the  dams is not in my 2D flow area, probably irrelevant, but the other one is circled in the first image. Here is the image:

I added all the necessary data that I know about (e.g., landcover) and went to run a hydrologic simulation but I got the error:

The "start" part of the connection refers to a pipe node that is not in geometry data.
The "end" part of the connection refers to a pipe node that is not in geometry data.

These errors were for both my dams, although, as I said, I can delete the upstream one if needs be.

I tried searching for a solution to this problem but couldn't find mention of this error anywhere.

I've added some images of my dam and the weir and culvert data I entered, in case it's helpful:




The only place in HEC-RAS that I can find mention of a "pipe node" is in the Unsteady Flow Data, but it's greyed out whether I select the flow area or the Connections:

If anyone has seen this error before and knows how to fix it, or has any suggestions for edits I can make, your help would be very much appreciated.

In case anyone else comes across this problem, here was how I fixed it.

Go to Edit Connection for your weir in the Geometric Data window.
Change Connections from Pipe Node to your 2D flow area by clicking on "Set SA/2D..."
I'm not sure why my connection was defaulting to pipe node, but that fixed the problem.

